# Internet Explorer 11 default document view mode to Edge

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, networking, intranet

I have windows 7 and IE 11 installed in my local machine. I working on ASP.NET, C# web application used bootstrap, Jquery etc.

I have created one checkbox dropdown list (ref: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Multiple-Select-MultiSelect-DropDownList-with-CheckBoxes-in-ASPNet-using-jQuery.aspx).

But my local intranet website is showing default document view mode 7 and check box drop down list look like this

[image]

But when on production it looks good see below screenshot, on production default document view mode is Edge (I don't know how.)

[image]

**Is there anyway, I can set default document view mode to Edge for all local intranet website users?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this meta  between `<head></head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

For your reference:
[Legacy document modes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)